# Angular [innerHTML] doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to bind html content to a div in my Angular 6 app but it doesn't work.

Here is the content:

```
let content = 'Hello <a routerLink="['/Soja']">Nick Soja</a> How are you ?'
```

Here is the html part:

```
<div class="content" [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Now only `Hello` is binded. I don't see the rest of the html content. The expected result is:

'Hello [Nick Soja](https://link.com) How are you ?'

What's wrong ?

Comment: did you try using  `  instead of   '  so that would be:  let content = `Hello <a routerLink="['/Soja']">Nick Soja</a> How are you ?`  replace first and last single quote with `

Answer (score 1):

You can't use angular directives inside the innerHTML input value, it expects valid HTML. So that HTML is stripped from the code.

The HTML string being converted to HTML by the innerHTML directive won't be compiled. So that also means you can't use things like databindings inside the HTML string.

Comment: Is there a workaroud to achieve or bypass this ?

Comment: The obvious workaround in this case would be to use `<a href="/Soja">Nick Soja</a>`

Comment: So is there a way to intercept this a link and redirect with routerLink from component ? I don't want the page reload

Comment: No, because the static HTML doesnt have any communication with the angular framework. I didn't realize a full page refresh would happen using href. I suggest doing the following: `<div class="content">{{content.prefix}}<a routerLink="[content.route]">{{content.name}}</a> {{content.suffix}}</div>`

Comment: Of course you would have to define a object containing those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the routerLink directive. I believe it doesn't work because [innerHTML] cannot compile angular directives and components, only static HTML.

Comment: Is there a workaroud to achieve or bypass this ?

Comment: something like this maybe:
In the component file:
`let item = {
  link: ['/Soja'],
  name: 'Soja'
};`

And in the html template file:
`<div class="content">
    Hello <a routerLink="item.link">{{item.name}}</a> How are you ?
</div>`

This should keep the link and the name dynamic

Answer (score 0):

just use: tick (``) instead of single quotes ''

content = `Hello <a routerLink="['/Soja']">Nick Soja</a> How are you ?`;

or try this: 
define your link in .ts file

`link = '/Soja'`

and bind it to router link in your template file

`<div class="content" >
      Hello <a routerLink="link">Nick Soja</a> How are you ?
</div>`

Comment: That will help to show the rest of the string, but won't fix the routerLink problem. See my answer with explanation.

Comment: @enf0rcer , you are correct.